# JSON.Net How to Serialize Dictionary<Enumeration, Enumeration>?

Tags: json

JSON.Net How to Serialize Dictionary ?

Or Dictionary, where MyClass contains two enumeration?

Comment: Do you mean, you have enumeration as a key? IEnumerable? And how its hash is being calculated?

Comment: Never mind, I went the long way and wrote a JsonConvertor

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
var reqUsers = from user in users
        select new
        {
            username = user.username,
            firstName = user.firstName,
            lastName = user.lastName,
            email = user.email
        };

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { users = reqUsers });
```